# Is it still possible to push a custom dimension on page view in GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Is it still possible to push a custom dimension on page view using GTM as pictured [here](http://tagmanagerpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/image-27.png)? I set up custom dimensions in GA but do not see the options for adding custom dimensions under More Settings for Page View in Tag Manager. If it possible what steps do you have to complete to enable it?

I don't have an option for this, and the image says "Track Type" which seems to be from an older version of the GUI.

[image: I don't have that option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tick the checkbox before "Enable override settings in this tag" (that, or set your custom dimension via the settings variable - but then they might be also used on events).

Comment: I needed to check "Enable overriding settings in this tag". Thanks.